# Finding what takes space in a docker image

Tags: docker

I'm looking for a visual tool that would take a Docker image and be able to show (in some kind of a chart) what makes the image e.g. 1,2GB large.

In addition to what disk tools would do, it would also tell me which Docker overlay brought that file in.

Is there such a tool or shall I dream on?

Answer (score 1):

[Dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) does it.

Mentioned [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18528423).